# How to write Extensible methods in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to write a method I will call on a string literal in JavaScript. A method that I want to call:

```
"Javascript".toKampala();
```

Does that feature exist in JavaScript? and if it does How do I write such a method `(toKampala())` on a JavaScript literal or any object?

In Kotlin I did it like this;

```
fun String.toHenry():String{
    return "$this Henry";
}
```

and I can call

```
"chalres".toHenry()
```

Comment: Henry, please do some research before asking a question on Stack Overflow. By searching for your question's title in google, I the answer could be found in the first search result.

Comment: I did But maybe I was using the same word like in the heading

Comment: Good I got the answer here Thanks

Comment: I literally copy-pasted _"How to write Extensible methods in javacript"_ into google to find these 2 dupe targets...

Comment: I actullay wanted to know if that method workes on all javascript objects

Comment: Pretty much, yea.

Comment: Thanks alot then

Comment: Another question. Sorry  Is it good practice to do this?

Comment: Depends on who you ask. Generally, as long as you know what you're doing, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `string` is default has a prototype, which is the `String.prototype` object and it can access anything which are defined there.

You need add that method in the `String.prototype` and it will be accessible from any `string`. You can access the current `string` in that function by `this`.

```js
String.prototype.toHenry = function() {
  return this + ' Hentry';
};

console.log('charles'.toHenry());
```

Comment: please give a small example

Comment: @henrybbosa See it

Comment: Please don't answer obvious duplicates like these. Close them as a duplicate instead Answering them disqualifies the (closed) duplicate from being [automatically deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba), and the answer only serves to further divide where information can be found.